# Openlayers- Show another Image Layer based on zooming region

Tags: image, zooming, openlayers, layer

Is it possible in OpenLayers to open another Image layer (OpenLayers.Layer.Image) from a base Image Layer based on certain predefined regions on the base Image Layer. For example if I have five regions set in my base Image Layer on zooming to any one region will open the respective Image layer and zooming out will bring back the base Image Layer?

If yes can you point some samples or method how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I found its possible in Openlayers using **OpenLayers.Layer.Image** to the map layer. Then creating a vector overlay layer denoting circles (**OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Overlay")**) and adding it to the map as overlay layer.

Then I register **zoomend** event of the map. Based on the getZoom() method I have the control to change the image using **map.setBaseLayer(imageLayer2)**

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge of such feature - different image layers based on regions. But maybe you'd be interested in self-hosted custom tiles? [Here's some information](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/UsingCustomTiles) of how it is set. The idea is: you create tile images (e.g. 256x256px) from your images and you just create many zoom levels from one big image. But at the areas of your interest, you change the tile images, that are present there. Downside is amount of actions, you have to do: you have to cut all your images to tiles (or not, if using big tiles), resize images for different zoom levels by hand, configure zoom levels and finally - change the tiles with regions of your interest. Needs some image editing, but should work.